# Need help on yaml side

Tags: github, pipe, devops, github-actions, cicd

I have one repo it has 3 yaml files for frontend, backend & admin frontend. Developer push on backend works on every time.
My 3 yamls running but frontend & admin frontend folder code have no changes in that time i need only backend yaml only run
remaining two yaml simply do nothing,

For my scenario if user pushes to backend code only backend ci only i need to run

How to configure that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the `paths` subtype in each of your workflow triggers.

I recommend to check the [Github official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-paths) for more details.

In your case, supposing that you have 3 folders following the structure below:

```
repository
    |__ backend
    |__ frontend
    |__ admin_fronted
```

For each workflow, you could user the following implementation:

```
name: Backend

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'backend/**'

jobs:
   [ ... ]
```

```
name: Frontend

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'frontend/**'

jobs:
   [ ... ]
```

```
name: Admin Frontend

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'admin_frontend/**'

jobs:
   [ ... ]
```

That way, each push will trigger a workflow only if at least a file in the specific path has been updated.

Note that there is also a `paths-ignore` subtype when you can use the opposite behavior if needed.